# PHP undefined constant testing

Tags: php, if-statement, constants

In PHP if I define a constant like this:

```
define('FOO', true);
if(FOO) do_something();
```

The method `do_something` gets executed as expected.

But if I don't define the `BOO` constant below:

```
if(BOO) do_something();
```

Then `do_something` also gets executed.  What's going on here?

Comment: Yeah, this "feature" of php makes me want to beat my face against my desk.  Especially when I meant `$boo`, but typed `boo`, in which case defined() isn't really even in the running.

Comment: Unexpected behavior indeed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
// BOO has not been defined

if(BOO) do_something();
```

`BOO` will be coerced into the string `BOO`, which is not empty, so it is truthy.

This is why some people who don't know better access an array member with `$something[a]`.

You should code with `error_reporting(E_ALL)` which will then give you...

> Notice: Use of undefined constant HELLO - assumed 'HELLO' in /t.php on line 5

You can see if it is defined with `defined()`. A lot of people use the following line so a PHP file accessed outside of its environment won't run...

```
<?php defined('APP') OR die('No direct access');
```

This exploits [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) - if the left hand side is true, then it doesn't need to run the right hand side.

Comment: The fallback to string already triggers a warning (no longer a notice) as of PHP 7.2.0, and will throw an error exception as of PHP 8.0.0. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration72.deprecated.php#migration72.deprecated.unquoted-strings.

Answer (score 6):

If you enable error logging, you'll see an error like the following:

> PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant BOO - assumed 'BOO' in file at line N

What's happening is that PHP is just arbitrarily assuming that you meant to use 'BOO' and just forgot the quotes. And since strings other than `''` and `'0'` are considered "true", the condition passes.

Answer (score 3):

If it's not the existance of the constant you want to test, but if you want to test the value of the constant you defined, this might be a better way: `if(BOO === true)` or `if(BOO === false)`

Answer (score 2):

PHP will automatically make the guess that you meant the string format, which a string will return true.

However you should use the [defined method](http://php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php):

> bool defined ( string $name )

So it would be:

```
if(defined('BOO')) {\\code }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if($FOO) do_something();
```

Just using FOO takes it as a value rather than the variable you defined. Better to use PHP's [defined](http://php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php).

Answer (score 2):

PHP is dynamically typed. You can achieve what you're trying to do with a function such as this:

```
function consttrue($const) {
    return !defined($const) ? false : constant($const);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use php's `constant()` function, as in:

```
if (constant('BOO')) doSomething();
```

*Remember to enclose the constant's name in quotes.*

Here is a [PHP replit](https://repl.it/@sherylhohman/php-undefined-constants-beware-of-truthy-conversion?language=php_cli&folderId=) demonstrating the examples below.

Ap per the [php docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php), if the constant is defined, its value is returned; otherwise, `null` is returned.

Since `null` is falsey, this will behave as expected.
This can be used in cases where you need to know if something is explicitly defined as `true` (or at lease a truthy value) vs either not defined, or defined with a falsey value.  This works particularly well when having a variable defined is the exception, or having it undefined could be a security risk.

```
if (constant('IS_DEV')) {
  // *Remember to enclose the constant's name in quotes.*
  // do stuff that should only happen in a dev environment
  // By Default, if it didn't get defined it is, as though, 'false'
}
```

Using `constant()` when checking against variables is a good practice to mitigate against security risks in certain situations. For example, printing out php info only if a certain constant is (defined and) TRUE.
As your question shows, PHP's string conversion would expose details if somehow the constant did not get defined.

Alternately, you could:

```
if (defined('IS_DEV') && (IS_DEV)) {
  // *Remember to enclose the constant's name in quotes for the FIRST operator.*
  // do stuff that should only happen in a dev environment
}
```

Another method that would work is to use `===` or `!==`, which tests exact equality (including type), without performing typecast a conversion.

```
if (IS_DEV === true)) {
  // do stuff that should only happen in a dev environment
}
```